# Can't Create Random Point in PaperJs per Documentation

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I am using the latest version of PaperJs but when I run the following code from their sample **the output is "NaN."**

```
window.onload = function () {
    paper.setup('myCanvas');
    with (paper) {
        // Create a point whose x is between 0 and 50,
        // and y is between 0 and 100
        var point = new Point(50, 100) * Point.random();

        console.log(point);
    }
}
```

[The code works online in sketch.paperjs.org](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/ZY9BDoIwEEWv8tMVGAJ14QbjyguYuBQXBSZCgI5pG9EY724LLIjOqvPz3s/0LbQaSOTi3JGrGpGIiuuwF6bQWCbLcDSkHEHhzq12GBu2hCdai5LcSKQhoXSNnUx+zJC+/sGtlGvwocxSfYCmEafwjnxbAGNs5iA1XuUhivfBXfsVa8s9pT3foqlnRvx/Sn95N0VW5Jfr5ws=) but doesn't work when I try locally via the code above or the following (also outputs "NaN"):

```
// Make the paper scope global, by injecting it into window:
paper.install(window);
window.onload = function () {
    // Setup directly from canvas id:
    paper.setup('myCanvas');

    // Create a point whose x is between 0 and 50,
    // and y is between 0 and 100
    var point = new Point(50, 100) * Point.random();

    console.log(point);
}
```

The following works, and all my other PaperJs code works; it's just that I can't seem to create a random point per the documentation.

```
console.log(new Point(50, 100), Point.random());
```

Outputs:

```
Point {x: 50, y: 100} Point {x: 0.8624748098043336, y: 0.8705165661914955}
```

The documenation: http://paperjs.org/tutorials/geometry/mathematical-operations/#random-values

Comment: Are you sure you use the paper.js language and not javascript? Because the multiply operator can't be overloaded in javascript, you have to use `pointA.multiply(pointB);`

Comment: @arthur.sw That was it!  I just had to do `view.size.multiply(Point.random());` as I was using javascript directly (not using type='text/paperscript') as per http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/ Thank you!!!

Comment: ok I posted an answer so that you can validate it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you use the *paper.js* language and not *javascript*?

Because the multiply operator can't be overloaded in javascript, you have to use `pointA.multiply(pointB);`.